# Indexar arrays 3D com Numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, array-multidimensional

Eu tenho um array em três dimensões (x, y e z) e um vetor de endereçamento. Esse vetor tem um tamanho igual ao da dimensão x do array, e o seu objetivo é para cada x apontar um y trazendo os seus respectivos z, ou seja, o resultado esperado é de dimensão (x, z).

Abaixo tem um exemplo de código, que funciona conforme esperado, mas alguém sabe se tem alguma função do Numpy com a qual eu possa substituir o loop for e resolver o problema de forma mais otimizada?

```
arr = np.random.rand(100,5,2)
result = np.random.rand(100,2)
id = [np.random.randint(0, 5) for _ in range(100)]
for i in range(100): 
    result[i] = arr[i,id[i]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código abaixo resolve o que você está tentando fazer. Comparei o seu código com o meu (setando o mesmo seed do gerador de números aleatórios) e os resultados foram iguais.

Repare que, ao invés de fazer um loop até 100, criei um *array* de 100 elementos com o método *np.arange()*. Usei este *array* como índice pra referenciar as posições de `arr`. Repare também que criei a variável `id` como um *array*, que aceita esse tipo de indexação avançada: `id[np.arange(100)]`.

```
arr = np.random.rand(100,5,2)
id = np.array([np.random.randint(0, 5) for _ in range(100)])
result = arr[np.arange(100), id[np.arange(100)]]
```

Uma dica, já que você quer eficiência: quando for criar um array e preenchê-lo depois (como fez no seu código), não crie usando *np.random.rand()*, use *np.zeros()*. Vai economizar a geração de valores aleatórios à toa. De qualquer forma, repare que no código acima isso nem foi necessário, o array `result` foi criado já preenchido.

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou bastante.